# When I register an user with CodeFirst EF6 MVC5 Asp.NET, results in duplicate tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I have the exact problem described here:
[Register custom UserProfile in ASP.NET MVC4 results in duplicate tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14836085/register-custom-userprofile-in-asp-net-mvc4-results-in-duplicate-tables#comment20793410_14836085)

But the solution doesn't work for me, because it's for MVC4 and I use the MVC5.

The problem is when I try to register a new user, duplicates almost all tables in database for a plural name, eg: Picture (duplicate to) Pictures

**Edit:**

I have an extended class from **IdentityUser**, named **ApplicationUser**, to put in this model additional attributes, like the id of postal code, photo and name:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Photo { get; set; }

        public int PostalCodeID { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("PostalCodeID")]
        public virtual PostalCode PostalCode { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Auction> Auctions { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Bid> Bids { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Message> Messages { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Friend> Friends { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<BlockHistory> Blocks { get; set; }
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser> {

        public DbSet<PostalCode> PostalCode { get; set; }

        public ApplicationDbContext()
            // ConnectionString
            : base("AuctionsContext", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }
}
```

The **PostalCodeID** is a foreign key for the table/model "PostalCode". One user can have one postalcode, but one postalcode could have zero or several users.

Here is the model "PostalCode":

```
public class PostalCode {
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression(@"\d{4}-\d{3}", ErrorMessageResourceType=typeof(Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName="PostalCodeFormat")]
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required")]
    [StringLength(8, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Length")]
    [Display(Name = "Name_PostalCode", ResourceType = typeof(Resources))]
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }

    public int LocalityID { get; set; }

    public virtual Locality Locality { get; set; }
}
```

I have the migrations enabled, but not in automatic mode,I think this is happening because in the **configuration.cs**, i have this code

```
    public Configuration() {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
    }
```

When I create the first migration, and updated the database, all tables were correctly created (with their names in singular), except the **AspNet***xxxx* tables, which are created automatically when the first user registration occurs, and that is when most tables are duplicated, and the weblogger gives this error:

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.AspNetUsers_dbo.PostalCodes_PostalCodeID". The conflict occurred in database "PSIProject", table "dbo.PostalCodes", column 'ID'.
The statement has been terminated.

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.AspNetUsers_dbo.PostalCodes_PostalCodeID". The conflict occurred in database "PSIProject", table "dbo.PostalCodes", column 'ID'.
The statement has been terminated.



Linha 164:                    PostalCodeID = model.PostalCodeID
Linha 165:                };
Linha 166:                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
Linha 167:                if (result.Succeeded)
Linha 168:                {
```

I understand what is happening which leads to this error, in some way, the IdentityUser can't find the **PostalCode** table, so, it creates the **PostalCodes** table, 
and it's on this table where it's created the relationship between the **PostalCodes** and **AspNetUsers** (I've checked, and there is no relation between tables **AspNetUsers** and **PostalCode**)

PS:
I've tried to put **[Table("PostalCode")]** before **public class PostalCode**, but when registering a user I got an error saying **dbo.AspNetUsers** is an invalid object so I verified the database and noticed that it wasn't creating those automatic **AspNet***xxxx* tables.

Comment: I faced something similar error very long back and I really don't remember the scenario but I was making some mistake while setting the foreign key in other model which led to duplicate tables. And for the pluralization of Table names its the default behaviour of entity framework but you can always stop it from doing it

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite difficult to understand, but I'm going to take a wild stab in the dark. If I'm completely off-based, feel free to let me know and provide additional information.

The default Entity Framework convention is to create table names as the pluralized versions of the entities they represent, so for a class like `Picture`, you would get a table in your database named `Pictures`, with an `s`. If you're getting "duplicates", I can only surmised that you're using an existing database or otherwise created the schema for the database manually instead of letting Entity Framework do it. In this manually created schema, you apparently named your tables in a singular fashion. I'm also assuming that you've got automatic migrations running or else you'd just get an error that the database is out of sync instead of duplicate anything. With automatic migrations, if Entity Framework determines that the database doesn't contain the schema it needs, it will update it accordingly automatically, which in your scenario would result in "duplicate" tables named in the convention that Entity Framework looks for.

You have two choices here. The best is to simply let the conventions be the conventions. Don't create your own schema or name your tables in your schema according to Entity Framework conventions (pluralized). With EF6 you can actually alter the conventions if you really care that much.

Option two is to prefix every entity class with the `Table` attribute to explicitly tell Entity Framework what table name it should look for, e.g.:

```
[Table("Picture")]
public class Picture
{
    ...
}
```

However, that's quite cumbersome and prone to error over the long haul of your application.

Comment: can look to my edir please?